# Should i create multiple services for multiple variables?

Tags: angular

In Angular 7, I'm creating a component that has many radio button groups. The values of each of these groups are coming from a database. Should I create 1 service to fetch all the values (although they are all independent of each other and have different structures) or should I create a service for each radio button group?

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-settings',
  template: '

  <mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="dropdown1">
    <mat-radio-button *ngFor="let c of dd1" [value]="c.id"> 
      {{c.description}}
    </mat-radio-button>
  </mat-radio-group>

  <mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="dropdown2">
    <mat-radio-button *ngFor="let c of dd2" [value]="c.id"> 
      {{c.description}}
    </mat-radio-button>
  </mat-radio-group>

  [...]

  ',
  styleUrls: ['./settings.component.css']
})
export class FtpSettingsComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() dropdown1: string;
  @Input() dropdown2: string;
  @Input() dropdown3: string;

  dd1: Array<{id: number, description: string}> = [...];
  dd2: Array<{id: number, description: string}> = [...];

  [...]

}
```

Comment: It depends on how you intend to use this service in other paces as well. If you always need to populate the specified data on the same page then you can have one component. If on other pages you want to use just subset of data then it is better to separate.

Comment: I see your point. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it really depends on the structure and url that you use to get data for that radio buttons! If they come from different urls and different datas should be parsed you better write separate services for each of them. Else if they are use same url api its better to include them in one service component